# How to get better performance with the following code

Tags: java, string, multithreading, performance

I'm trying to get this code to run faster. With big strings it takes too much time. I don't know much about multithreading but i'd like to try to divide it into threads to help get faster results but i don't really get how to do it.

Where do i start and what can i do?

The following code looks throught the string trying to find substrings which are put in manually.

First line asks for the string.
Second line asks for a number of strings that you'll try to find,
then you input the strings that you're looking for that are no longer than 4 and no shorter than 1.

In the output you get how many times a substring was in the string.

```
    BufferedReader br;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String getLine = br.readLine();

    if (getLine.length() < 1 || getLine.length() > 1000000) {
        getLine = br.readLine();
    }

    getLine = getLine.toUpperCase();

    String helpNumber = br.readLine();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(helpNumber);

    if(number < 1 || number > 100000){
        helpNumber = br.readLine();
        number = Integer.parseInt(helpNumber);
    }

    String[] shortCuts = new String[number];

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        shortCuts[i] = br.readLine();
        if(shortCuts[i].length()>=1 && shortCuts[i].length()<=4) {
            shortCuts[i] = shortCuts[i];
            shortCuts[i] = shortCuts[i].toUpperCase();
        }else i--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.println(count(getLine, shortCuts[i]));
    }

}

private static int count(final String string, final String substring) {
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while ((index = string.indexOf(substring, index)) != -1) {
        index++;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

I want to make this code run faster.

Comment: Can you give some data that shows what the execution time is?  How are you timing the code?  I don't see any code to compute times.

Comment: We've got a test site for that. Don't know who wrote it and i can't give access to it but all i know is that with short strings it takes under a sec, and with longer ones over 2 secs which is considered a failure by tests. When i try to messure it myself it also counts typing time which i don't know how to omit.

Comment: Hm... I wonder if it would pass if you replaced the `count` function with one that you write yourself that doesn't use `indexOf`?  It should be approximately the same time, but there's a chance that it's just fast enough to pass your tests?

Comment: Eliminate typing time by using a StringReader instance in the BufferedReader that supplies all the input for the program.

Comment: Or just use `System.console().readLine()`. Then, remove nonsensical checks like `getLine.length() > 1000000` (why is that a reason to repeat the read) and redundant operations, like `shortCuts[i] = shortCuts[i];`. The actual search operation can be accelerated by using the [Boyer–Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm), but it won’t do much for these small search strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 'slow' part of the code is the counting of the sub string in the String invoked here

```
 for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.println(count(getLine, shortCuts[i]));
    }
```

A thought to speed up the following operation

`private static int count(final String string, final String substring)`

is to invoke it into number of logical processor in your system. You'll need to understand and read about [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Hence, you'll be able to break down the array `shortcuts` size `n` into partition depending on the logical processor in your machine `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` Combine the result in the end and return when all thread reach completion.

Comment: @Khatyrius Please mark is as answered if it answered your question